# How do you hide a Gtk# window?

Tags: mono, gtk#

How can I hide a Gtk# window that I created in MonoDevelop? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();
    this.HideAll();
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

---

**Solution**
Calling `HideAll()` outside the constructor, as tomlog suggested, works. If you want to do some work before showing the window you can

- Add an event handler to `Window.Shown` *before* calling `Build()`
- Do the work before calling `Build()` (probably the better alternative in most cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can call HideAll in the constructor, because the form is not fully initialized and therefore not visible yet.